# Create a list of texts which are separated by '+' and '-'

Tags: string, perl

I have a text in following manner

```
@@+aaa+bbb+ccc-asd-asdfg+hhh
```

I need to separate the text into two lists:

- Those starting with `+`: `'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'hhh'`
- Those starting with `-`: `'asd', 'asdfg'`

I did `$str = substr($str, 2);` to remove the `@@`.

Comment: Why not split with `/[@+-]/` or even `/\W+/`?

Comment: Sorry for missing this out. I need to have elements preceded by '+' in separate list and those preceded by '-' in separate list

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: If you don't know Perl then this is the wrong place to start learning, and you mustn't consider Stack Overflow to be a source of free software solutions. However, there are many links in [Stack Overflow's ***Perl*** tag information page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info)
that would help. Please read them carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use 2 regexes to get all chars other than `-` and `+` after `-` and `+`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text = "@@+aaa+bbb+ccc-asd-asdfg+hhh";

my @lstplus = $text =~ /\+\K[^+-]+/g;
my @lstminus = $text =~ /-\K[^+-]+/g;
```

See the [online Perl demo](https://ideone.com/Tw31NQ)

Here, `\+` matches a literal `+` and `-` matches a literal `-`, then `\K` omits this symbol from the match and `[^+-]+` matches and returns a chunk of 1+ chars other than `-` and `+`.

Comment: This is not working in cases when the text is like this `+aaa+bbb+ccc`

Comment: @Anyone who chances to see the comment above, see OP's question: *I need to have elements preceded by '+' in separate list and those preceded by '-' in separate list.*

Answer (score 2):

I would use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to divide your string on `+` or `-` and store each element in an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/ say /;

my $text = '@@+aaa+bbb+ccc-asd-asdfg+hhh';

my @words = split(/[+-], $text);

shift @words if $words[0] =~ /^@/;

say for @words;
```

Comment: Regarding your update, yes it produces the required output. But who said that there are only ever "at signs" `@` at the start of the string? If you're working only from this one sample then you may as well write `say for qw/ aaa bbb ccc asd asdfg hhh /`.

Comment: `/[+-]/` a bit cleaner than `/\+|-/`

Comment: The OP was happy with `substr($_, 0, 2)`, so even an unconditional `shift(@words)` should do.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP edited his question so this is no longer correct.